# Top align JQuery UI tooltip popup

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-tooltip

I need help to align jquery UI tool tip popup on the top of the element.

This is my code so far

JSbin: http://jsbin.com/teqori/2/edit?html,css,js,console,output

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).tooltip({
    items:'a[tip]',
    position: {
        my: "top",
        at: "right top",
    },
    content: function(){
        if($(this).is('[tip]')){
            var src = $(this).attr('tip');
            return '<img class = "toolTipPopUp" src ="'+src+'">'
        }
    }
    });
});
```

CSS

```
    img.productImg {
        border: 1px solid;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        height:800px;   
    }

    img.toolTipPopUp{
        border: 1px solid;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        height:600px;   
    }
```

HTML

```
<a tip = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/84/March_5_1895_San_Francisco_Call_newspaper.png/444px-March_5_1895_San_Francisco_Call_newspaper.png"><img class = "productImg"  src = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/84/March_5_1895_San_Francisco_Call_newspaper.png/444px-March_5_1895_San_Francisco_Call_newspaper.png"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the link to be inline block

```
a[tip] { display: inline-block; }
```

and the position to

```
position: {
    my: "left top",
    at: "left top"
},
```